# jQuery unobtrusive custom adapter and method in jsFiddle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, jsfiddle, unobtrusive-validation

I cannot make this jsFiddle work but it works in the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/jYq2X/

I am trying to add a new custom rule to compare two fields. The custom adapter works, it is being called and setting the options. But the custom method is never called.

I am executing this JS on DOM ready:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customequal-method", function (val, el, p) {
    var $other = $(el).closest('form').find('input[name=' + p.other + ']'); 
    return $other.length && $other.val() == val;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("customequal", ["other"],
                                     function (options) {
                                         options.rules["customequal-method"] = options.params;
                                         options.messages["customequal-method"] = options.message;
                                     });



$(function(){
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#myform'));
    $('[type=button]').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); $('form').valid();});

    $('input[type=text]').blur();
})
```

These are the fields in HTML:

```
    <input type="text" name="StartDate2" id="StartDate2" value="2"
           data-val="true" data-val-customequal="xx xxx" data-val-customequal-other="EndDate2"/>   
    <input type="text" name="EndDate2" id="EndDate2" value="3"
           data-val="true" data-val-customequal="xx xx" data-val-customequal-other="StartDate2"/>
```

I have been trying different things but nothing seems to work.

Any idea?

Comment: The question is not about `jsfiddle`.  Removed [tag:jsfiddle] tag.

Comment: @Sparky so the link to the JsFiddle example must be irrelevant to debugging this?

Comment: @TheOptimusPrimus, for the same reason every single SO question containing a fiddle isn't tagged [tag:jsfiddle].

Comment: Then it looks like there is a lot of moderation work to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsfiddle

Comment: @Sparky I am afraid the question IS about jsFiddle. That code works in a browser, but not in jsFiddle. And that was the whole reason of this post.

Comment: @vtortola, then I suggest you update your OP since you never mentioned that it works fine in your browser.  And if it works in the browser, why does it matter that it's not working in the jsFiddle?

Comment: As the answer says in the first solution, because I was not using the right option to initialize that JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Your fiddle is not working because:

- all your code runs in the DOM ready so you are adding your custom `unobtrusive.adapters.add` after the unobtrusive.validator plugin called `unobtrusive.parse(document)` which registers all the inputs without your custom validator
- if you call [.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) multiple times it **only registers the rules for the first time** and does not override them on subsequent calls. So although you've called `unobtrusive.parse` again in the DOM loaded this time with the custom adapter added it still won't have any effect.

## So you have two ways to fix it:

**Register your custom adapters before the DOM loaded event**, you can do this with changing your fiddle to use

```
"No wrap - in <head>"
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd3W4/).

### Or

**Remove the already added validator object** with using `$('#myform').data('validator', null)` before calling `unobtrusive.parse` manually:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myform').data('validator', null);

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#myform'));
    $('[type=button]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form').valid();
    });

    $('input[type=text]').blur();
})
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDDrk/).